# How find org entries that are missing a certain property?

Tags: org-mode, search

I have this long sub-tree, I want to find the entries that I haven't set a certain property on yet.

```
* Big list
** foo
   :PROPERTIES:
   :QUUX:     1
   :END:
** bar
   :PROPERTIES:
   :END:
** baz
   :PROPERTIES:
   :QUUX:     2
   :END:
```

I'm trying to use org-sparse-tree, but can't figure out how to write the predicate.

It should return the `bar` entry in the example, the entry with no QUUX property.

edit: currently using org-column-view to find the blank cells.

Comment: Is it?:  `(org-entry-get nil "QUUX")`  That will return the result if it is found, or nil if it is not found.  To try that out, place your cursor on the `bar` subtree and evaluate `M-:` the above-mentioned expression, and the result is nil.